# How to keep on genrating random values untill the given condtion is satisfied without going into infinte iterations?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to generate random values for some purpose which satisfy some condition. For ex- Two variables 'a' and 'b' and the condition is a+b>30
and i want random values for a and b. The problem is that i am facing an infinite loop as it is not able to satisfy the condition.

I have used `eval()` to evaluate the condition as my condition is in string format. I have tried using `random.randrange`.

```
var=[{a:'Value',b:'Value'},{},{}]
cond=[['a+b>20'],[],[]]

class check_condition:

    def condition(self,cond,var,i):
        for k,v in var[i].items():
                exec("%s=%s" % (k,v))

        for j in range(len(cond[i])):
            while eval(cond[i][j])==False:
                reassign(var,i)


class variable:

    def assign(self,var):
        for i in range(len(var)):
            for k,e in var[i].items():
                var[i].add(k,random.randrange(10,30))


    def reassign(self,var,i):
        for k,e in var[i].items():
            #print("Reassigning")
            var[i].add(k,random.randrange(10,30))
```

NO errors but i need to know some improved logical statement.

Comment: Minimal working example would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generate two arrays of all possible values:

```
as = range(10,30)
bs = range(10,30)
```

Choose two random values:

```
a = random.choice(as)
b = random.choice(bs)
```

Check your condition, and if false, then pop those two items and continue the loop:

```
as.remove(a)
bs.remove(b)
```

---

Update - this is not a good solution, because it allows for only 20 out of 400 combinations.

In addition to that (or more precisely - as a result of that), it can also end without success.

So here is a more complete solution, which chooses randomly from all possible combinations:

```
import random

aa = range(10,30)
bb = range(10,30)

combinations = [(a,b) for a in aa for b in bb]

while True:
    (a,b) = random.choice(combinations)
    if a+b == 30:
        print(a,b)
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest another approach:

1. Generate all possible pairs of numbers (a, b) given some limited
   range for both of them. Your code highlights range (10, 30].
2. Filter out all pairs that sums to a number lesser than 30
3. Use something like random.choice to select a random pair of numbers from rest of As and Bs

Benefit of such approach is that it would never fall into infinite loop - it's just indexing operation using random integer.